# using rlang to list variables inside purrr::pmap

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to write a function called `grouped_lm,` which basically runs linear regression models for each level of the combination of grouping variables (`grouping.vars`) for multiple criterion/dependent (`crit.vars`) and predictor/independent variables (`pred.vars`).

This is done in such a way that first entry into `crit.vars` is regressed onto `pred.vars`. 
For example, if I enter `grouping.vars = am`, `crit.vars = c(mpg, drat)`, and `crit.vars = c(wt, disp)` (in the context of `mtcars` dataset), the function will run two regression models (`mpg ~ wt` and `drat ~ disp`) for each level of grouping variable `am` (`am = 0` and `am = 1`).

I have managed to create a dataframe from entered variables, write a custom function that runs linear regression models, but can't seem to figure out how to use `rlang` to get entered variables into the list elements that will be entered into `purrr::pmap`.

Apologies for a lengthy question and thanks in advance for any help offered.

```r
# libraries needed
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# function definition
grouped_lm <- function(data,
                       grouping.vars,
                       crit.vars,
                       pred.vars) {

  #================== preparing dataframe ==================
  #
  # check how many variables were entered for criterion variables vector
  crit.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(crit.vars)))
  crit.vars <-
    if (length(crit.vars) == 1) {
      crit.vars
    } else {
      crit.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for predictor variables vector
  pred.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(pred.vars)))
  pred.vars <-
    if (length(pred.vars) == 1) {
      pred.vars
    } else {
      pred.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for grouping variable vector
  grouping.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(grouping.vars)))
  grouping.vars <-
    if (length(grouping.vars) == 1) {
      grouping.vars
    } else {
      grouping.vars[-1]
    }

  # getting the dataframe ready
  df <- dplyr::select(.data = data,
                      !!!grouping.vars,
                      !!!crit.vars,
                      !!!pred.vars) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data = ., !!!grouping.vars) %>%
    tidyr::nest(data = .)

  # checking if the nested dataframe looks okay
  cat(paste("the entire nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df)             # the entire nested dataframe
  cat(paste("first element of the list column from nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df$data[[1]])   # first element of the list column

  #============== custom function ================

  # custom function to run linear regression for every element of a list for two variables
  lm_listed <- function(list.col, x_name, y_name) {
    fx <- glue::glue("scale({y_name}) ~ scale({x_name})")

    # this tags any names that are not predictor variables (used to remove intercept terms)
    filter_name  <- glue::glue("scale({x_name})")

    # dataframe with results from lm
    results_df <-
      list.col %>% # running linear regression on each individual group with purrr
      purrr::map(.x = .,
                 .f = ~ stats::lm(formula = as.formula(fx),
                                  data = (.))) %>% # tidying up the output with broom
      purrr::map_dfr(.x = .,
                     .f = ~ broom::tidy(x = .),
                     .id = "group") %>% # remove intercept terms
      dplyr::filter(.data = ., term == !!filter_name) %>% # add formula as a character
      dplyr::mutate(.data = ., formula = as.character(fx)) %>% # rearrange the dataframe
      dplyr::select(
        .data = .,
        group,
        formula,
        term,
        estimate,
        std.error,
        t = statistic,
        p.value
      ) %>% # convert to a tibble dataframe
      tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

    # return the dataframe
    return(results_df)
  }

  # check if the function works
  group_mtcars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$am)
  fn_results <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(group_mtcars),
    x_name = list('wt', 'disp'),
    y_name = list('mpg', 'drat')
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  # seems to be working!
  cat(paste("the custom function seems to be working!: \n"))
  print(fn_results)

  #========= using  custom function on entered dataframe =================
  cat(paste("running the custom function on the entered dataframe: \n"))
  # running custom function for each element of the created list column
  df_lm <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(df$data),
    x_name = list(!!!pred.vars),
    y_name = list(!!!crit.vars)
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  #============================== output ========================

  print(df_lm)
  # return the final dataframe with results
  return(df_lm)
}

# example usage of the function
grouped_lm(
  data = iris,
  crit.vars = c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
  pred.vars = c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width),
  grouping.vars = Species
)
#> the entire nested dataframe: 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species    data             
#>   <fct>      <list>           
#> 1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>
#> 3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>
#> first element of the list column from nested dataframe: 
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Petal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1         5.10         1.40        3.50       0.200
#>  2         4.90         1.40        3.00       0.200
#>  3         4.70         1.30        3.20       0.200
#>  4         4.60         1.50        3.10       0.200
#>  5         5.00         1.40        3.60       0.200
#>  6         5.40         1.70        3.90       0.400
#>  7         4.60         1.40        3.40       0.300
#>  8         5.00         1.50        3.40       0.200
#>  9         4.40         1.40        2.90       0.200
#> 10         4.90         1.50        3.10       0.100
#> # ... with 40 more rows
#> the custom function seems to be working!: 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   group formula                   term    estimate std.error     t p.value
#>   <chr> <chr>                     <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 0     scale(mpg) ~ scale(wt)    scale(~   -0.768     0.155 -4.94 1.25e-4
#> 2 1     scale(mpg) ~ scale(wt)    scale(~   -0.909     0.126 -7.23 1.69e-5
#> 3 0     scale(drat) ~ scale(disp) scale(~   -0.614     0.192 -3.20 5.20e-3
#> 4 1     scale(drat) ~ scale(disp) scale(~   -0.305     0.287 -1.06 3.12e-1
#> running the custom function on the entered dataframe:
#> Error in !pred.vars: invalid argument type
```

Created on 2018-03-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**Edits after the answer was provided**

I was also wondering how I can get separate columns in the ouput for every grouping variable. So, with the answer provided below, if I run-

```r
grouped_lm(
  data = mtcars,
  crit.vars = c(wt, mpg),
  pred.vars = c(drat, disp),
  grouping.vars = c(am, cyl)
)
```

It works, but the output looks something like this:

[image]

As can be appreciated from the picture, it is not at all clear what do the values 1 to 6 represent. So it will be nice to also get a separate column for each grouping variable provided so that, in this example, there will be two columns `am` and `cyl` with their respective levels for each `lm` model.

(I have manually created this dataframe. This is not how the grouping is happening, but this is just to show what the desired output looks like.)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need to replicate the same behavior as in the example usage of 'mtcars' where the `x_name` and `y_name` are strings rather than `symbols` (which is the case of 'pred.vars' and 'crit.vars'), convert those to strings with `quo_name` i.e.

```
df_lm <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(df$data),
    x_name = map(pred.vars, quo_name),
    y_name = map(crit.vars, quo_name)
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  #============================== output ========================

  print(df_lm)
  # return the final dataframe with results
  return(df_lm)

}
```

Or pass as `symbol` without any evaluation i.e. with `!!`

```
df_lm <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(df$data),
    x_name = pred.vars,  ###
    y_name = crit.vars   ###
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  #============================== output ========================

  print(df_lm)
  # return the final dataframe with results
  return(df_lm)

}
```

This has to do with how the `lm_listed` function is taking the arguments.  Consider the objects as strings

```
sl <- "Sepal.Length"
sw <- "Sepal.Width"
```

and `glue` returns it correctly

```
glue::glue("scale({sl}) ~ scale({sw})")
#scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width)
```

Now, we change this to `symbol`, it also works

```
sl <- rlang::sym("Sepal.Length")
sw <- rlang::sym("Sepal.Width")
glue::glue("scale({sl}) ~ scale({sw})")
#scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width)
```

But, the problem is in using `!!` for evaluating that is passed as input argument

```
sl <- !!rlang::sym("Sepal.Length")
```

> Error in !rlang::sym("Sepal.Length") : invalid argument type

The `!!` is evaluated outside the environment of `tidyverse` functions, which result in the error

-full code

```
grouped_lm <- function(data,
                       grouping.vars,
                       crit.vars,
                       pred.vars) {

  #================== preparing dataframe ==================
  #
  # check how many variables were entered for criterion variables vector
  crit.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(crit.vars)))
  crit.vars <-
    if (length(crit.vars) == 1) {
      crit.vars
    } else {
      crit.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for predictor variables vector
  pred.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(pred.vars)))
  pred.vars <-
    if (length(pred.vars) == 1) {
      pred.vars
    } else {
      pred.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for grouping variable vector
  grouping.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(grouping.vars)))
  grouping.vars <-
    if (length(grouping.vars) == 1) {
      grouping.vars
    } else {
      grouping.vars[-1]
    }

  # getting the dataframe ready
  df <- dplyr::select(.data = data,
                      !!!grouping.vars,
                      !!!crit.vars,
                      !!!pred.vars) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data = ., !!!grouping.vars) %>%
    tidyr::nest(data = .)

  # checking if the nested dataframe looks okay
  cat(paste("the entire nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df)             # the entire nested dataframe
  cat(paste("first element of the list column from nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df$data[[1]])   # first element of the list column

  #============== custom function ================

  # custom function to run linear regression for every element of a list for two variables
  lm_listed <- function(list.col, x_name, y_name) {
    fx <- glue::glue("scale({y_name}) ~ scale({x_name})")

    # this tags any names that are not predictor variables (used to remove intercept terms)
    filter_name  <- glue::glue("scale({x_name})")

    # dataframe with results from lm
    results_df <-
      list.col %>% # running linear regression on each individual group with purrr
      purrr::map(.x = .,
                 .f = ~ stats::lm(formula = as.formula(fx),
                                  data = (.))) %>% # tidying up the output with broom
      purrr::map_dfr(.x = .,
                     .f = ~ broom::tidy(x = .),
                     .id = "group") %>% # remove intercept terms
      dplyr::filter(.data = ., term == !!filter_name) %>% # add formula as a character
      dplyr::mutate(.data = ., formula = as.character(fx)) %>% # rearrange the dataframe
      dplyr::select(
        .data = .,
        group,
        formula,
        term,
        estimate,
        std.error,
        t = statistic,
        p.value
      ) %>% # convert to a tibble dataframe
      tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

    # return the dataframe
    return(results_df)
  }

  # check if the function works
  group_mtcars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$am)
  fn_results <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(group_mtcars),
    x_name = list('wt', 'disp'),
    y_name = list('mpg', 'drat')
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  # seems to be working!
  cat(paste("the custom function seems to be working!: \n"))
  print(fn_results)

  #========= using  custom function on entered dataframe =================
  cat(paste("running the custom function on the entered dataframe: \n"))
  # running custom function for each element of the created list column

  df_lm <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(df$data),
    x_name = pred.vars,
    y_name = crit.vars
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  #============================== output ========================

  print(df_lm)
  # return the final dataframe with results
  return(df_lm)

}
```

-run the function

```
res <- grouped_lm(
  data = iris,
  crit.vars = c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
  pred.vars = c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width),
  grouping.vars = Species
)
```

-output printed

```
#the entire nested dataframe: 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    data             
#  <fctr>     <list>           
#1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>
#2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>
#3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>
#first element of the list column from nested dataframe: 
# A tibble: 50 x 4
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width
#          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1         5.10         1.40        3.50       0.200
# 2         4.90         1.40        3.00       0.200
# 3         4.70         1.30        3.20       0.200
# 4         4.60         1.50        3.10       0.200
# 5         5.00         1.40        3.60       0.200
# 6         5.40         1.70        3.90       0.400
# 7         4.60         1.40        3.40       0.300
# 8         5.00         1.50        3.40       0.200
# 9         4.40         1.40        2.90       0.200
#10         4.90         1.50        3.10       0.100
# ... with 40 more rows
#the custom function seems to be working!: 
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  group formula                   term        estimate std.error     t   p.value
#  <chr> <chr>                     <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 0     scale(mpg) ~ scale(wt)    scale(wt)     -0.768     0.155 -4.94 0.000125 
#2 1     scale(mpg) ~ scale(wt)    scale(wt)     -0.909     0.126 -7.23 0.0000169
#3 0     scale(drat) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)   -0.614     0.192 -3.20 0.00520  
#4 1     scale(drat) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)   -0.305     0.287 -1.06 0.312    
#running the custom function on the entered dataframe: 
# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  group formula                                  term               estimate std.error     t         p.value
#  <chr> <chr>                                    <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 1     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.743    0.0967  7.68 0.000000000671 
#2 2     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.526    0.123   4.28 0.0000877      
#3 3     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.457    0.128   3.56 0.000843       
#4 1     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.332    0.136   2.44 0.0186         
#5 2     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.787    0.0891  8.83 0.0000000000127
#6 3     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.322    0.137   2.36 0.0225
```

-result output

```
res
# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  group formula                                  term               estimate std.error     t         p.value
#  <chr> <chr>                                    <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 1     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.743    0.0967  7.68 0.000000000671 
#2 2     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.526    0.123   4.28 0.0000877      
#3 3     scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width) scale(Sepal.Width)    0.457    0.128   3.56 0.000843       
#4 1     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.332    0.136   2.44 0.0186         
#5 2     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.787    0.0891  8.83 0.0000000000127
#6 3     scale(Petal.Length) ~ scale(Petal.Width) scale(Petal.Width)    0.322    0.137   2.36 0.0225
```

---

If we need to have the 'grouping.vars' also in the output

```
grouped_lm <- function(data,
                       grouping.vars,
                       crit.vars,
                       pred.vars) {

  #================== preparing dataframe ==================
  #
  # check how many variables were entered for criterion variables vector
  crit.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(crit.vars)))
  crit.vars <-
    if (length(crit.vars) == 1) {
      crit.vars
    } else {
      crit.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for predictor variables vector
  pred.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(pred.vars)))
  pred.vars <-
    if (length(pred.vars) == 1) {
      pred.vars
    } else {
      pred.vars[-1]
    }

  # check how many variables were entered for grouping variable vector
  grouping.vars <-
    as.list(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::enquo(grouping.vars)))
  grouping.vars <-
    if (length(grouping.vars) == 1) {
      grouping.vars
    } else {
      grouping.vars[-1]
    }

  # getting the dataframe ready
  df <- dplyr::select(.data = data,
                      !!!grouping.vars,
                      !!!crit.vars,
                      !!!pred.vars) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data = ., !!!grouping.vars) %>%
    tidyr::nest(data = .)

  # checking if the nested dataframe looks okay
  cat(paste("the entire nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df)             # the entire nested dataframe
  cat(paste("first element of the list column from nested dataframe: \n"))
  print(df$data[[1]])   # first element of the list column

  #============== custom function ================

  # custom function to run linear regression for every element of a list for two variables
  lm_listed <- function(list.col, x_name, y_name) {
    fx <- glue::glue("scale({y_name}) ~ scale({x_name})")

    # this tags any names that are not predictor variables (used to remove intercept terms)
    filter_name  <- glue::glue("scale({x_name})")

    # dataframe with results from lm
    results_df <-
      list.col %>% # running linear regression on each individual group with purrr
      purrr::map(.x = .,
                 .f = ~ stats::lm(formula = as.formula(fx),
                                  data = (.))) %>% # tidying up the output with broom
      purrr::map_dfr(.x = .,
                     .f = ~ broom::tidy(x = .),
                     .id = "group") %>% # remove intercept terms
      dplyr::filter(.data = ., term == !!filter_name) %>% # add formula as a character
      dplyr::mutate(.data = ., formula = as.character(fx)) %>% # rearrange the dataframe
      dplyr::select(
        .data = .,
        group,
        formula,
        term,
        estimate,
        std.error,
        t = statistic,
        p.value
      ) %>% # convert to a tibble dataframe
      tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

    # return the dataframe
    return(results_df)
  }

  # check if the function works
  group_mtcars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$am)
  fn_results <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(group_mtcars),
    x_name = list('wt', 'disp'),
    y_name = list('mpg', 'drat')
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  # seems to be working!
  cat(paste("the custom function seems to be working!: \n"))
  print(fn_results)

  #========= using  custom function on entered dataframe =================
  cat(paste("running the custom function on the entered dataframe: \n"))
  # running custom function for each element of the created list column

  df <- df %>%
          tibble::rownames_to_column('group')  
  df_lm <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(
    l = list(df$data),
    x_name = pred.vars,
    y_name = crit.vars
  ),
  .f = lm_listed) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
    left_join(df) %>%
    select(!!!grouping.vars, everything()) %>%
    select(-group, -data)   



  #============================== output ========================

  print(df_lm)
  # return the final dataframe with results
  return(df_lm)

}
```

-run function

```
r1 <- grouped_lm(
   data = mtcars,
   crit.vars = c(wt, mpg),
   pred.vars = c(drat, disp),
   grouping.vars = c(am, cyl)
 )
```

-output

```
r1
# A tibble: 12 x 8
#      am   cyl formula                  term        estimate std.error        t   p.value
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  1.00  6.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)   -0.101     0.995 -  0.102   0.935  
# 2  1.00  4.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)   -0.226     0.398 -  0.568   0.591  
# 3  0     6.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)    0.307     0.673    0.456   0.693  
# 4  0     8.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)   -0.119     0.314 -  0.379   0.713  
# 5  0     4.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)    0.422     0.906    0.466   0.722  
# 6  1.00  8.00 scale(wt) ~ scale(drat)  scale(drat)   -1.00    NaN      NaN     NaN      
# 7  1.00  6.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)    1.00      0      Inf       0      
# 8  1.00  4.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)   -0.835     0.225 -  3.72    0.00991
# 9  0     6.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)    0.670     0.525    1.28    0.330  
#10  0     8.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)   -0.535     0.267 -  2.00    0.0729 
#11  0     4.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)    0.932     0.362    2.57    0.236  
#12  1.00  8.00 scale(mpg) ~ scale(disp) scale(disp)    1.00    NaN      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! One minor change I observed is that `group` variable in the output is now a number rather than the actual values of the levels of the `grouping.vars`. So, for example, in the code I had posted, `group` was a factor with three levels of `Species` of Iris flower, but now it is a number 1 to 3 denoting three levels of this factor. Is there any possibility to retain that behavior? Otherwise, it's hard to understand which level of the entered factor variable do 1,2,3, etc. correspond to.

Comment: I have edited my question now that contains a more general version of my comment here.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil  Based on the output you showed,  You can add a `mutate` i.e. `%>% mutate(grpNew = cumsum(group == 1))`

Comment: Thanks. Can you include this in your answer as well with the test I used: ```grouped_lm(
  data = mtcars,
  crit.vars = c(wt, mpg),
  pred.vars = c(drat, disp),
  grouping.vars = c(am, cyl)
)```. I tried this line of code, but I am still getting numbers rather than the name and levels of grouping variables.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil  I was reading your description.  What exactly do you need as output

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient description of what I was expecting. I have now edited the question to also include of not only what is currently the output but the output I desire. Thanks!

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil  Updated the output.  If you have more questions, please post as a new question.  Also, it is better to post small chunks of code rather than the entire script

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this will be the end of this question. Yeah, I've been trying to figure out how to do a `reprex` with all the information contained in it without letting the length of the code blow up. Will be more attentive to this issue in future. Thanks again for the help; much appreciated.